How to prioritize a specific entity when collision boxes overlap in RealityKit
So in my RealityKit scene, I have a safe entity that opens when tapped and a key entity positioned inside the safe. Both entities have their collision shapes generated with generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true).

After I do a tap to open the safe, its collision box still covers the one of the key's, preventing the latter from receiving gesture events.
I'm wondering if there's a way to "prioritize" the collision of the key entity, so that it will respond to interactions even when its collision box is blocked by another entity's?
I tried changing the order in which I loaded the entities and created the collision shapes, but things kept the same.

Solution A – Collisions' Filtering
In RealityKit for iOS, visionOS and macOS, developers use a combination of a CollisionGroup and a CollisionFilter to prevent a certain model from colliding with unwanted object. CollisionGroups are not directly assigned to entities, so CollisionFilters define the collision properties for entities instead. Use the bitwise shift (<<) when defining each collision group's value.
let group01 = CollisionGroup(rawValue: 1 << 0)     //  2^0 = 1
let group02 = CollisionGroup(rawValue: 1 << 1)     //  2^1 = 2
let group03 = CollisionGroup(rawValue: 1 << 2)     //  2^2 = 4

Swift's bitwise operator should be applied for bit-shifting in order to create a unique index for each group, where each subsequent index is greater by one than the sum of the previous two. Collision bitmasks are also widely used in SceneKit.
let wizardMask = CollisionGroup.all.subtracting(group01)
let specialFilter = CollisionFilter(group: group01, mask: wizardMask)
myModel.collision?.filter = specialFilter

Solution B – Custom Collision Shape
If for some reason the first solution doesn't work for you, then use the second one. For that, create a custom collision shape that simply won't allow an unwanted collision to happen.

This post is also helpful.
